# Was the late Murray S. Klamkin ONLY an expositor?

Tags: math-history

The late Murray S. Klamkin did a lot of mathematics expository writing, but I was wondering if that was ALL he did. So, my question is: Did the late Murray S. Klamkin ever come up with a deep-dive mathematics result of the order of, say, Suslin’s theorem (that there is an analytic subset of the reals that is not Borel)?

Comment: @JeanMarie: It says 'page not found' :(

Comment: Sorry: it is https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/Murray-S-Klamkin-2061185006